# Vue TypeScript Cookie auth

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have some problems with Vue Typescript authentication.
I have 2 files, Auth.ts and Api.ts. So every time when the user is logged in, API needs to update the token for Authentication, but I will need to refresh the page for that.

So here is the deal. Starting with Api.ts

```
export default function useCometAPI(secured_api = true) {
  const error = ref(null);

  const Token: Ref<string | undefined> = ref(
    useCookies().cookies.get("token")
  );

  const { CurrentUserToken } = useAuth(); // not used in that case

  console.log("test " + Token.value);
 
  const API_URL: ComputedRef<string> = computed(() => {
    const RAW_URI = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000");
    RAW_URI.port = "8000" || "80";
    return RAW_URI.href;
  });

  const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      Authorization: `Bearer ` + Token.value,
    },
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" || API_URL.value,
    withCredentials: true,
  });
```

as you see I have CurrentUserToken that is const from the Auth function, but it's not used in that case, because it's not even updated from there. So why I did `const Token like that is, because I have a function to update that token, and it looks like this:

```
const setToken = async (token: string) => {
    Token.value = token;
  };
```

And I'm calling that function in Auth file like:

```
const Login = async (payload: ILogin): Promise<void> => {
    await get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(() => {
      post("/api/auth/login", payload)
        .then((response: any) => {
          cookie.set("token", response.data.data.token);
          setToken(response.data.data.token);
          Token.value = response.data.data.token; // Even trying with direct const
          _populateReactivity(response);
          router.push({ name: "home" });
        })
        .catch((e: any) => {
          notify({
            type: "error",
            title: e.response.data?.message,
          });
        });
    });
  };
```

So here is that function _populateReactivity, that is setting CurrentUserToken (I mentioned it in Api.ts), and It's still not updated in the Api.ts file. And here is how it looks:

```
const _populateReactivity = (result: any): void => {
    CurrentUserToken.value = cookie.get("token") ?? result?.data.data.token;
    CurrentUser.value = result?.data.data.name;
  };
```

I tried to put cookies in the computed function, but we all know it could not work.

So I didn't show the full code, but Api.ts has get, post, drop... methods as functions, and I'm calling that get method in Auth.ts for example:

```
const put = async (
    path: string,
    payload: Record<string, any>,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    try {
      return AxiosInstance.put(path, payload, config);
    } catch (e) {
      const err: any = e;
      error.value = err.response.data;
      throw e;
    }
  };
```

And those methods are called before exporting useAuth function like:

```
const { get, post, drop, setToken, Token } = useCometAPI(true);

export default function useAuth() {
```

Solution (I hope not to use it) is to call all methods separately for example in login function like:

```
const Login = async (payload: ILogin): Promise<void> => {
    const { get, post, setToken, Token } = useCometAPI(true);
    await get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(() => {
       post("/api/auth/login", payload)...
```

And it would work, but is that the best solution? I think there should be a simpler one to update that useCometAPI function because it's called before exporting Auth function, and it's blocking it from updating, as I said, when I refresh the page it would work
Any ideas on how to simplify this?